# How long does ignore_user_abort(true); persist?

Tags: php

I made a script that shouldn't return anything to the browser (not any echo, print or interruptions of the code with blank space, like `?> <?`, and that uses `ignore_user_abort(true);` to avoid that, once the browser window is closed, the process stops.

Thus once the script is launched, it should go till the end.

The script is designed for newsletter, and it sends one email each 5 seconds, to respect spam policies of my provider, through `mail();`

Said that, what's happening is that after about 20 minutes working (the total emails are 1002 ), the script "collapses", with no error returned.

Hence my question: is there a life time limit for scripts are running with `ignore_user_abort(true);` ?

**EDIT**
Following the suggestion of Hanky (here below) I put the line:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

But the issue persists

Comment: I think your host has a timelimit of 20 min for a script to run exactly to avoid that

Comment: Check `max_execution_time`, `memory_limit`, error logs.

Comment: Hi Julio: to avoid what? My kind of script? Then it's a problem with newsletter. But I need to send these newsletters. Not certainly to spam.

@Justinas I have not access to Logs :-/

Comment: `ini_get('max_execution_time');` returns 120
`ini_get('memory_limits');` returns 512M

Comment: Just use something like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor. They have the infrastructure for sending newsletters and will have white-listed IP addresses. If you’re mass-mailing from a shared host (which is sounds like you are) it’s IP address will be quickly black-listed (if not already). With it being shared, you’ll piss other tenants off, as well as your hosting provider, who may terminate your account.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Martin; if you are using a PHP script to send emails, at least consider using AWS SES and route it through their SMTP server. This will prevent IP blacklisting.

Comment: I do'nt tjink I can send what I need frm these email servers, caus I have my own code/structure and I have not clue how they can put the correct data into the template I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So whilst `ignore_user_abort(true);` will prevent the script stopping after a visitor browses away from a page, it is `set_time_limit(0);` that will remove the time limit. You can also change the PHP memory_limit in your php.ini or by setting something like `php_value memory_limit 2048M` in your .htaccess file.

In order to list the default max_execution time you can run `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');` (seconds) or `echo ini_get('memory_limits');` (megabytes).

This being said, it sounds like your PHP scripts are better suited to being run from the [CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php). Using the command line you can run PHP scripts, this sounds better suited to your usage as it seems, from what you have described, the script doesn't really need to serve anything to the web browser. This method is better for PHP scripts that are run in order to operate a background process rather than to return a front-end to the user.

You can run a file from the command line simply by running `php script.php` or `php -f script.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there was not way to solve the issue. Also the provider still investigating.
Meanwhile following your suggestions, I was able to make it running. I created a TEST file and I fired it to verify:

```
exec("/php5.5/bin/php -f /web/htdocs/www.mydomain.tld/home/test.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

In worked. I setup a `sleep(600);` and I sent 6 emails + one that inform me when the process is really finished.
It runs in a transparent way till the end.

Thank you so much for your support